Can NextJs 14+ be configured to swap in layouts at build time?
I am building a NextJs web app (v14) which I hope to use for more than one website. Each website will be identical except for the look and feel. For this reason at build time I need some way to specify which base layout to use for that build. Is this at all possible?

That's possible, when you do some deployment progress you can add one value in your .env file for example NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_LAYOUT=layout1. Value layout1 is based on what your value expected when deployment or build process. Then, in your app.js check it like this.
// pages/_app.js
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/globals.css';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const Layout = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_LAYOUT === 'layout1'
    ? require('../components/Layout1').default
    : require('../components/Layout2').default;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default MyApp;

Or, you can separate the build in your package.json. For example
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:layout1": "NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_LAYOUT=layout1 next build",
    "build:layout2": "NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_LAYOUT=layout2 next build"
  }
}


Interesting. Thanks for the suggestion but this looks like the old-style pages router. I'm using app router (which I think is new in NextJs 14 although if I'm honest I'm just learning NextJs and 14 is all I've used). Any idea how to do something similar in v14?
